# Reliably read serial data in C++

Tags: c++, arduino, serial-port

I am running an Arduino program at 200Hz and sending three uint32 from Arduino over serial (at 115200) and then processing them in Ubuntu C++ program.

So far I have tried sending it in binary as a struct, but sometimes the data comes in corrupted - probably because there is no specified start/end of the data.

```
int r = read(fd, &incoming_data, sizeof(arduino_data_t));
```

I have also tried sending it as one line string "uint32_1 uint32_2 uint32_3\n" but that sends not one, but multiple samples at a time and then I don't know how to parse it. I have just noticed that the string is ended with null character.

Can you tell me what approach is better and give me an advice on how to make it work?

Many thanks

Comment: When you sending uint32 between Arduino and a PC, you need to be aware of [Endianness](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness), Arduino is little endian, but your ubuntu could be using big endian.

Comment: @hcheung `but your ubuntu could be using big endian.` Possible, but quite unlikely. Nearly all modern PC are little endian. Some rare exceptions include old Sun servers and old macs that use PowerPC. Still, I agree that one should always keep endianness in consideration.

Answer (score 1):

You need to match the data formats used by both arduino and ubuntu programs.

In order to distinguish the data, it is better to convert the binary data of uint32 to a hexadecimal string and send and receive it.
Then, put a delimiter with a return or line feed code for each of the three data.
Although it is not essential programmatically, it will be easier for humans to read it by inserting commas between each uint32 data.

The serial port communicates in 1-byte units at a minimum. There is no concept of packets like TCP/IP.
You need to get and save the data and size of the read() result and add a process to check if all the data was received normally.
The received data is packed in a large buffer from the beginning and added.

If data can be lost or corrupted due to noise or overrun, you will need to apply techniques such as flow control, packet header and checksum/CRC, as in @mmomtchev's answer.

The data is analyzed from the beginning of the buffer, and after confirming that the total of the three uint32 data and the delimited data is the correct size, one data is cut out and passed to the processing of one set of data.

In data processing, a hexadecimal string is converted to uint32 binary data, and then the data is stored or passed to another process.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to be able to gracefully recover from transmission errors and then to continue reading.

I recommend that you enable some kind of flow control if you haven't already done so. As the receiving UART is on the computer side, this one will usually be a good UART that will be able to buffer incoming data - so even if you are not reading, data will not be lost.

Then instead of sending 3 32-bit words, send 4 32-bit words, the first one being some kind of value that is impossible. Then make a state machine and read byte by byte:

```c
uint32_t incoming_data[4];

int i = 0;
while (i < 4) {
  int r = read(fd, &incoming_data[i], 1);
  if (incoming_data[i] == MAGIC_VALUE) i = 0; // restart from 0
  else i++;  // proceed to next byte
}
// we have successfully read 4 bytes in incoming_data
```

If you cannot afford to read invalid data, you will also have to add some additional bytes with a CRC check.